# What is the difference between dd_rescue and ddrescue, when to prefer which one?

Tags: data-recovery, software-rec, gnu, forensics

There are two similar tools for a dd on bad hardware:

- Kurt Garloff's [dd_rescue](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/ddrescue/)
- GNU [ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html)

**What is the difference between dd_rescue and ddrescue, when to prefer which one?**

Comment: related: [*What's the difference between ddrescue, gddrescue, and dd_rescue?*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211578/whats-the-difference-between-ddrescue-gddrescue-and-dd-rescue)

Comment: @sebasth Thank you for the link. In the ubuntu question it is rather discussed why there are 3 names. The answer is, ubuntu invented the third. There is no discussion about the functionality. This makes sense, if the question is on askubuntu and not the unix.sx.

Comment: Someone suggested to close this question, but forgot to add a hint here how to improve the question in her/his opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `ddrescue` first quickly copies good blocks using a large block size and then optionally tries to recover more data reading smaller blocks within the blocks that failed in the first pass. This requires a log file that records what areas are still missing and the output must go to a file or disk that allows random access. If run again with the log file present, `ddrescue` will try again reading the missing parts only.

Kurt Garloff's `dd_rescue` copies the data in sequential order, allowing it to be captured on stdout, e.g. to compress it before writing it to a file. When a read error is encountered `dd_rescue` switches temporarily to a smaller block size to try to recover data from the problematic area before continuing with the remainder of the disk.